# Is E(X|Y) $\sigma(X)$-measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

From the definition of conditional expectation, we have that E(X|Y) is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. I wonder if E(X|Y) is also $\sigma(X)$ measurable? It seems to be true since E(X|Y) is a "coarser" version of X.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily. Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two independent coinflips, i.e. $P(X_i = 1) = 1-P(X_i = 0)$ and let $S = X_1 + X_2$. The probability space $\Omega$ has four points: $\{0,0\}, \{1,0\}, \{0,1\}, \{1,1\}$. Now, $\sigma(S) = \sigma(\{0,0\}, \{\{0,1\},\{1,0\}\}, \{1,1\}).$ However, 
$$E[S | X_1] = c_0 1_{X_1 = 0} + c_1 1_{X_1 = 1},$$
and neither $\{X_1 = 0\}$ nor $\{X_1 = 1\}$ are in $\sigma(S)$, so $E[S|X_1]$ is not $\sigma(S)$-measurable.

Answer (score 4):

No.  For a counterexample, let $\Omega = \{a,b,c\}$ be a sample space with three points, $\mathcal{F} = 2^\Omega$, and $P(A) = \frac{1}{3} |A|$ so that every point gets probability 1/3.  Let $X = 1_{\{a,b\}}$ and $Y = 1_{\{b,c\}}$.  If $Z = E[X \mid Y]$, verify that $Z(a) = 1$ and $Z(b) = Z(c) = \frac{1}{2}$.  On the other hand, every $\sigma(X)$-measurable random variable $W$ satisfies $W(a) = W(b)$.